# export is not recognize in cmd while Cygwin is installed

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, cygwin, export

My machine is running win7 64bit. I installed Cygwin and added `C:\cygwin64\bin` to the `PATH`. Now linux commands work on cmd , but `export` is not recognized:

> 'export' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

while it works properly in Cygwin64 Terminal. How should I add it to windows default cmd?

Comment: Just because you added C:\cygwin64\bin to your path doesn't mean Windows can magically use Linux commands now. Cygwin is a Linux emulator, it doesn't give your computer new functionality. If you want to run Linux commands in Windows, install [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: @SomethingDark That won't magically give the OP an `export` command. It is a `bash` built-in command.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### `export` is not recognized in `cmd`.

> 'export' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Let's open a `bash` shell and look for the `export` command:

```
DavidPostill@Hal /f/test
$ which export
which: no export in (.:/home/DavidPostill/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Windows/system32:/c/Windows)
```

That tells us that there isn't a program called `export`.

So what is it?

> export is a bash built in command.

Source [export](http://ss64.com/bash/export.html).

It has no meaning outside of a `bash` shell.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Bash command line for Linux](http://ss64.com/bash/) -  An excellent reference for all things Bash command line related.
- [export](http://ss64.com/bash/export.html) - Set an environment variable. Mark each name to be passed to child processes in the environment.

Comment: So, what is the alternative for export in cmd?

Comment: @ShreyasSG [set](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) or [setx](http://ss64.com/nt/setx.html)

Answer (score 25):

In Windows use `set` instead of `export`.

Comment: 'get' as variable, which you're initializing variable using 'set' instead of 'export'

Comment: set works as an echo command too.
to get the the variable value you can do: set VARIABLE_NAME

Comment: I can set it variable using 'set' but how do I get variable?

Comment: type only 'set' without quotes.

Answer (score 4):

```
EXPORT SQUAD_DIRECTORY ="/path/to/SQUAD"
```

Alternative for export in windows is `SET` :

```
SET SQUAD_DIRECTORY ="/path/to/SQUAD"
```

Refer : https://ss64.com/nt/set.html

Answer (score 0):

'set export' work for me on windows 10